# In a RPC, how does a receiver identify the senders architecture?

Tags: rpc

I am trying to wrap my head around how the sender identifies the endianness of the sender. I know the initial byte is usually the architecture/type of the sender. For example 0x00 is i386 etc. However, how does the first byte help at all if the receiver has no idea how to interpret it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endianness refers to the ordering of bytes into larger numbers, not the order of bits inside a byte. A single byte is always endian-safe; networks transfer byte streams transparently (that is, bytes are received in the same order in which they were sent).

Comment: So in an RPC the receiver can simply read the first byte regardless? If the sender wanted to send "0x01" wouldn't a bigendian receiver see "0x10" ?

Comment: If anything they would see `0x80`, but again, that's not what endianness does. Endian swapping turns `0x1234` into `0x3412`, but `0x01` stays `0x01`. In other words, endian swapping swaps entire bytes, not bits. So yes, the receiver can just read the first byte.

Comment: Bah, I always forget endianness swaps the bytes not bits etc. Thanks! That makes a lot more sense.